# Perform SELECT using WHERE IN clause on JSON Object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, string-searching

I have a json column in MySQL which contains a list of items for eg.

```
"style": {"style1", "style2", "style3", "style4", "style5"}
```

I want to search all the rows which contain the styles I specify through an array like IN clause like `WHERE style IN(["style1", "style3"])`

So I want to get all the rows which will match the string items from array exactly like how the `WHERE IN()` clause works in MySQL.

Is there any workaround or easy way to get this working?

Please help.. Thanks

Comment: The tables and models have already been setup and I don't have any control over it. I was looking for JSON_CONTAINS, JSON_SEARCH but could not find a satisafactory solution. I have updated the question and added a little more description of what I want.

Comment: Small point of order, but your example JSON should use [] instead of {}. Just in case that's compounding the issue...

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problema using MySQL JSON_TABLE – Map a JSON object to a relational database table.

Cheers

Comment: Some detail and implementation specifics would be welcome.